# Dont work script in playlist template wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want customize standart template playlist in wordpress with [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141767/), and I could it: i added one more field description on template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wp-playlist-current-item">
    <# if ( data.image ) { #>
    <img src="{{ data.thumb.src }}"/>
    <# } #>
    <div class="wp-playlist-caption">
            <span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-title">&#8220;{{ data.title }}&#8221;</span>
            <# if ( data.meta.album ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-album">{{ data.meta.album }}</span><# } #>
            <# if ( data.meta.artist ) { #><span class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-artist">{{ data.meta.artist }}</span><# } #>
            <# if ( data.description ) { #><a class="wp-playlist-item-meta wp-playlist-item-description">Song text</a><# } #>
    </div>
    **<# if ( data.description ) { #>
        <div class="wp-playlist-item-description-text">{{ data.description }}</div>
    <# } #>**
</script>
```

And I applyed some css style with this div:

```
.wp-playlist-item-description-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

That I see:

[my output playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OmBA.png)

But I cant applyed some jQuery scripts to my code and my tags. I want can show/hide this element with click, but Crome say me, that cant find it: zero elements found by selector.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".wp-playlist-item-description").click(function(){
      $('.wp-playlist-item-description-text').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Can you help me please, guys?